# Extract email from ListItem user

Tags: list-item

I don't know how to extract the email of a User in a Sharepoint list.
I get a FieldUserValue but I am stuck at it.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection listitems = list.GetItems(query);

            context.Load(listitems);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (ListItem item in listitems)
            {
                FieldUserValue fuv = (FieldUserValue)item["MyUser"];

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection listitems = list.GetItems(query);

context.Load(listitems);
context.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ListItem item in listitems)
{
   FieldUserValue fuv = (FieldUserValue)item["MyUser"];

   User user = context.Web.EnsureUser(fuv.LookupValue);
   context.Load(user);
   context.ExecuteQuery();

   string email = user.Email;
}
```

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380878/how-to-get-sharepoint-user-object-from-the-assignedto-field-using-client-side)